# 80/20 Alumunium Extrusion Non magnetic nuts sourcing parts

Tags: materials

I am in the process of building some device scafolding for a system that I would like to be as non magnetic as possible. It easy enough to source non magnetic screws and the like but the nuts that are designed to go inside the t slots on the extrusions have been imposible for  me to find in anything other then stainless steel. My usual go to sources (Mcmaster and the like) do not carry anything like brass, allumnium or even stainless 316. Does anyone have a source that makes these kinds of 80/20 nuts in any of those materials?

Thanks in advance

TL;DR I want [https://www.mcmaster.com/t-slot-screws/framing-type~t-slot-1/](https://www.mcmaster.com/t-slot-screws/framing-type%7Et-slot-1/) in brass aluminum or stainless 316

Comment: Might need to make them. By the way, forming 300 series stainless steel can cause it to become ferromagnetic when cold worked, which if it's a nut, will be due to tapping, cutting, or forming.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: limit material to brass and bronze. As commented ; stainless will be partly magnetic and aluminum threads tend to gall.

Comment: Monel s good but costly.

Comment: I tap aluminum all the time with no issues. Galling only occurs with metal on metal friction when the metals are a similar due to atomic forces afaik. Aluminum T nuts should be fine if they're strong enough. If there are aluminum screws too there could be galling, but I think only at high loads, since the passivization layer provides some protection.

Comment: @Drew Well, you don't tap dry, nor do you just leave the tap sitting in the hole for weeks, and taps aren't just steel but hardened steel which all helps. It certainly makes things worse if the metals are the same but they don't need to be (or else built-up edge wouldn't be an issue which I think is a form of galling). I use steel bolts in aluminum all the time though because....c'mon.

Comment: So what would the problem be if he bought some aluminum bar stock of the right dimensions. Then, cut drilled and tapped it to essentially make a T-Nut? He could pair that with any non-magnetic screw. I doubt galling would be an issue during the screw installation. And if it turned out to be, a bit of grease should fix it.